# It is possible to import a third-party js file in react app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, extjs, import

I have a js file from another project (mvc) that creats a simple table with extJS.

I'm creating a react app (create-react-app) with navbar and sidebar and my objective is to try to import that js file for the main content of react app

js file:

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({ enabled: true });

Ext.define('TestExtJsPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.testGrid',
    title: 'Simpsons',
    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
    columns: [
        { header: 'Name', dataIndex: 'name' },
        { header: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email', flex: 1 },
        { header: 'Phone', dataIndex: 'phone' }
    ],
    height: 200,
    width: 400,
    viewConfig: {
        trackOver: true,
        stripeRows: true,
        markDirty: false
    },
    initComponent: function () {
        var me = this;

        me.store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            storeId: 'simpsonsStore',
            fields: ['name', 'email', 'phone'],
            data: {
                'items': [
                    { 'name': 'Lisa', "email": "lisa@simpsons.com", "phone": "555-111-1224" },
                    { 'name': 'Bart', "email": "bart@simpsons.com", "phone": "555-222-1234" },
                    { 'name': 'Homer', "email": "home@simpsons.com", "phone": "555-222-1244" },
                    { 'name': 'Marge', "email": "marge@simpsons.com", "phone": "555-222-1254" }
                ]
            },
            proxy: {
                type: 'memory',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    root: 'items'
                }
            }
        });

        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});

Ext.Loader.setConfig({ enabled: true });

Ext.define('TestExtJsPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.testGrid',
    title: 'Simpsons',
    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
    columns: [
        { header: 'Name', dataIndex: 'name' },
        { header: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email', flex: 1 },
        { header: 'Phone', dataIndex: 'phone' }
    ],
    height: 200,
    width: 400,
    viewConfig: {
        trackOver: true,
        stripeRows: true,
        markDirty: false
    },
    initComponent: function () {
        var me = this;

        me.store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            storeId: 'simpsonsStore',
            fields: ['name', 'email', 'phone'],
            data: {
                'items': [
                    { 'name': 'Lisa', "email": "lisa@simpsons.com", "phone": "555-111-1224" },
                    { 'name': 'Bart', "email": "bart@simpsons.com", "phone": "555-222-1234" },
                    { 'name': 'Homer', "email": "home@simpsons.com", "phone": "555-222-1244" },
                    { 'name': 'Marge', "email": "marge@simpsons.com", "phone": "555-222-1254" }
                ]
            },
            proxy: {
                type: 'memory',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    root: 'items'
                }
            }
        });

        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

**My question is:**

It is possible to import this js file to a react app?
I need to do some change in js file to import it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get access to any variables defined using `var` on others scripts (connected before your script and unlabelled like `async`).

Well, if you connect your js file before your react-app code you can access all variables declared using `var`.

For example

index.html

```html
<html>
...
  <body>
    <script src="js-file.js" />
    <script src="react-code.js" />
  </body>
</html>
```

js-file.js

```
var mySharedVariable = "Example";
```

react-code.js it's webpack bundle (js result of `npm run build`)

```
...
export class MyComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return mySharedVariable;
  }
}
...
```

MyComponent will render string "Example"

If you use typescript you must declare mySharedVariable before using like

```
declare let mySharedVariable: string;
```

Why you can't use `async` script? You can read [this](https://medium.com/@raviroshan.talk/async-defer-javascript-loading-strategies-da489a0ba47e) article

**UPD**

So, lets do it together step-by-step

1) Create react app using cra

```sh
npx create-react-app my-app
```

2) Create file external.js and put it in public folder (next to the index.html) (If you have remote file pass this step)

```
var external = "external";
```

3) Modify your index.html file (append one line before closing body tag)

```html
<body>
  <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <!--
    This HTML file is a template.
    If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

    You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
    The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

    To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
    To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
  -->

  <!-- src is path to your js file -->
  <script src="external.js"></script> <!-- add this line -->
</body>
```

4) Modify your App.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
      <h1>{external}</h1>
  );
}

export default App;
```

5) Lets start your app

```sh
npm run start
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203213/discussion-on-answer-by-saveli-tomac-it-is-possible-to-import-a-third-party-js-f).